# Changing individual elements of numpy array based on its value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to iterate over every element of an numpy array and change its value in a semi-random manner. The reason for that is, that I'll apply that method to different arrays: I want them to be changed but I don't want them to be changed the same way.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
with np.nditer(smatrix, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
    for element in it:
        if element < 0:
            element = element - uniform(0.1,0.2)
        if 0 <= element < 0.05:
            element = uniform(0.15,0.3)
        elif 0.05 <= element < 1:
            element = 0
        elif 1 == element:
            element = 1
```

Another possibility:

```
for element in np.nditer(smatrix, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    if element < 0:
        element = element - uniform(0.1,0.2)
    if 0 <= element < 0.05:
        element = uniform(0.15,0.3)
    elif 0.05 <= element < 1:
        element = 0
    elif 1 == element:
        element = 1
```

However, the resulting array looks exactly the same as the inital array...

I'm relatively new to programming and stuck regarding this matter for quite a while. It would be awesome if someone could give me a hint on how to solve it and ideally a short explanation. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply transformation to every cell of `numpy.array` then `numpy.vectorize` is right tool for that.
Firstly you need function, which will use content of single cell as input, which itself will be feed to `vectorize` and which `return` desired value, see code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
def f(x):
    if x < 0:
        return x-random.uniform(0.1,0.2)
    if 0 <= x < 0.05:
        return random.uniform(0.15,0.3)
    if 0.05 <= x < 1:
        return 0.0
    if x == 1:
        return 1.0
    return x
vf = np.vectorize(f)

data = np.array([-4.3,0.03,0.9,1.0,1.9])
altered_data = vf(data)
```

Output (might be bit different for you as it is partially random):

```
[-4.48922564  0.19609667  0.          1.          1.9       ]
```

As you can check, it worked as intended for all values. Note that I added "do nothing to element" behavior (`return x`) as safety measure, in case element will be greater than `1`.

For more info regarding `numpy.vectorize` read [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

EDIT: Fixed issue reported in comment, problem was that `f` sometimes `return`ed `int` and sometimes `float`, while it should always `return` `float`.

Comment: I tried your solution with different 2D arrays, and discovered an issue if the first value = 1

Examples:

    data = np.array([[0.02,0,0.1,1],[1,0.05,0,0.01]])
    [[0.17426108 0.25596603 0.         1.        ]
     [1.         0.         0.29732222 0.23448857]]

    data = np.array([[1,0,0.1,1],[1,0.05,0,0.01]])
    [[1 0 0 1]
     [1 0 0 0]]

Comment: `vectorize` performs a trial calculation to determine the return dtype.  To skip that define a `otypes` parameter.   `vectorize` can be handy if you must use a scalar function on a multidimensional array, but it is slow - slower than a more explicit Python iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think `nditer` needs a stronger disclaimer.  It isn't a good iteration tool for beginners.  It is tricky to use right, and isn't particularly fast.  This Python version is really a stepping stone toward using it in compiled code, as illustrated with the `cython` example at the end of the main `nditer` page:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

There are faster ways of doing this kind of array calculation, but I'll try to explain why your `nditer` doesn't work.

The problem is with basic Python iteration.  In loop like:

```
alist = [0,0,0]
for element in alist:
    element = 1
```

`alist` is not modified.  The `element=1` just reassigns the `element` variable, but does not modify the iteration variable itself.    Instead you have mutate `element` itself, if that's possible.

With `nditer` the iteration variable is an `ndarray` itself, and is mutable:

```
In [69]: smatrix = np.zeros((2,2),int)                                          
In [70]: with np.nditer(smatrix, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it: 
    ...:     for element in it: 
    ...:         print(element, type(element)) 
    ...:         element[...] = 1 
    ...:                                                                        
0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
In [71]: smatrix                                                                
Out[71]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

If this isn't clear, look more carefully at the examples in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html.  Notice the use the `out` parameter, and expressions like `x[:] = [-1, -2, -3]`.

If this talk of mutating variables is confusing, it's a good indication that `nditer` is too advanced a tool at this point.